# Will a subclass also inherit from the super class of it's parent?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class named **Food**, a subclass of it named **Chicken**, then a subclass of the latter which is named **Fillet**. Will the Fillet class also inherit from the Food class? Also, is it right to call Fillet as another subclass of the Food class?

Comment: Yes, Your `Fillet` class will also be `Food`. Whether that is right or not is a bit hard to answer without a real world example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html);

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.
> Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

So `Fillet` is a descendant of `Food` and subclass of `Chicken`.

It will inherit explicitly from the super class of its parent depending on access modifiers used in top most class.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Yes, to both questions. Every subclass inherits all behavior and methods from all its parents (if they're visible).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on access specifiers **private**, **public**, **protected**.
All **public** members of `Food` will be inherited by `Fillet`.

I think source code will help you a lot.

```
class base 
{
    public:
        int x;
    protected:
        int y;
    private:
        int z;
};

class publicDerived: public base
{
    // x is public
    // y is protected
    // z is not accessible from publicDerived
};

class protectedDerived: protected base
{
    // x is protected
    // y is protected
    // z is not accessible from protectedDerived
};

class privateDerived: private base
{
    // x is private
    // y is private
    // z is not accessible from privateDerived
}
```

Comment: How about the protected members of Food?

Comment: Yes you can use `protected` members of Food if you inherit using **public** access specifier.